# How to integrate google contacts api in node webkit

Tags: google-api, desktop-application, google-apps, node-webkit, hello.js

I need to integrate google contacts import in my `nw.js` app. How should I create the `google app` ? When I create the app as web app, it asks for `redirect uri` which is not available for desktop apps. I'm not clear about how to implement google integration for desktop apps. Can anyone help me on this. ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in OAuth for desktop applications, when instead of `http://domain` you will redirect to `app://something` and you application will be started or receive a callback.

To make this, in your application you need to open request token url in new window (new window in your node-webkit app).

Also: [google docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) and [node-webkit github issue](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1016) and [other issue](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/542) about this.

---

For me I thought better would be open a default browser, there is a high chance that user already authenticated, and then just need to click "allow". So I start simple webserver inside node-wekit app and redirect to localhost.

You can see implementation in my project https://github.com/Paxa/postbird/blob/90cfb53b1775310eb2f262c8b54c9dba15b5cc0a/app/heroku_client.js#L185

To open default browser I use command "open" (only for mac)

```
child_process.spawn('open', [url]);
```

I also try to close browser window when user redirected back, it works but not always.

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.end("<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>");
```

May be I should also make a window active when receive redirect back (didn't try it yet):

```
var currentWin = require('gui').Window.get();
currentWin.focus();
```

If google not allows to make localhost as a callback url, you can try to use some domain (even free) and point it to 127.0.0.1 or use http://readme.localtest.me/

Comment: For multiplatform support can use https://github.com/pwnall/node-open
It opens file or url in system's default app

Comment: But how will u connect to the nw.js database from the opened webpage ?

Comment: Your application start a web server on some port, then user's browser will be redirected to `http://localhost:12345/something` and  you will receive it as incoming request.